# UserInput in Python While loop

Tags: python

Following my code which is supposed to take 3 positive integer as input from user. However, it is not working as per expectation.

```
def getPositiveNumber(prompt):
    timeUnits = (input("This is the numnber of time units to simulate > "))
    numAtoms = (input("How many atoms should we simulate ? "))
    radBeaker = (input("The radius of the beaker is ? "))
    while True:
         if timeUnits.isnumeric() and numAtoms.isnumeric() and radBeaker.isnumeric():
         print("All your values are integers")
         break

     else:
         timeUnits = input("This is the number of units to simulate. >")
         numAtoms = input("How many atoms should we simulate ? ")
         radBeaker = input("The radius of the beaker is ? ")
return timeUnits, numAtoms, radBeaker
```

This results in asking the input again after the initial 3 inputs have been placed but i want it to ask again right after the initial part if I put a non number.

Comment: If you want an integer, you can use the int fuction. This will simply force the user to enter an integer.

Comment: First, fix the indentation. The code, as posted, is invalid. Second, as one number at a time and do not proceed to the next number until you get the previous one right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def getPositiveNumber(prompt):
  timeUnits = None
  numAtoms = None
  radBeaker = None
  while True:
    timeUnits = input('This is the numnber of time units to simulate > ')
    numAtoms = input('How many atoms should we simulate ? ')
    radBeaker = input('The radius of the beaker is ? ')
    if timeUnits.isnumeric() and numAtoms.isnumeric() and radBeaker.isnumeric():
      print 'All your values are integers'
      break
  return (timeUnits, numAtoms, radBeaker)
```

Comment: Did you try it? (Hint: no.)

Comment: @Joey Try this solution and tell me it is working for you or not??

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in writing three almost identical code fragments to read three integer numbers. You need one function that gets one number. You can call this function three times or, in fact, as many times as you like:

```
def get_positive_int(prompt):
    while True:        
        possibly_number = input(prompt + "> ")
        try:
            number = int(possibly_number)
        except ValueError: # Not an integer number at all
            continue
        if number > 0: # Comment this line if it's ok to have negatives
            return number
```

The function relies on the fact that any string recognized by `int()` is a valid integer number. If it is, the number is returned to the caller. If it is not, an exception is raised by `int()` that keeps the loop going.

Example:

```
>>> get_positive_int("This is the number of units to simulate")
This is the number of units to simulate> ff
This is the number of units to simulate> -10
This is the number of units to simulate> 25
25
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the test to check if the input is a positive integer to a function

```
def is_positive(n):
    """(str) -> bool
    returns True if and only if n is a positive int
    """
    return n.isdigit()
```

Next you can create a function to ask for a positive integer. For this avoid the `str.isnumeric` method because that returns `True` for floats as well. Rather, use the `str.isdigit` method.

```
def request_input(msg):
    """(str) -> str
     Return the user input as a string if and only if the user input is a positive integer
    """
    while True:
        retval = input(msg)
        if is_positive(retval):
            return retval
        else:
            print("Please enter a positive integer")
```

`request_input` will loop forever until a positive integer is received. These simple blocks can be combined to achieve what you want. In your particular case:

```
def get_user_inputs(prompt):
    time_units = request_input("This is the number of time units to simulate > ")
    num_atoms = request_input("How many atoms should we simulate ? ")
    rad_breaker = request_input("The radius of the beaker is ? ")
    return time_units, num_atoms, rad_breaker
```